# How to format the size of multiple link images in a power point simultaneous (2007)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, power, microsoft-powerpoint, format

I've a powerpoint with one link image on each slide. I must update these images regularly but when I do, the size format of each link image changes. Can someone tell me, without using a macro, a simple way of simultaneous format the size (it's the same for each one of them) of all these link images on each slide?

Comment: I don't think you will find a non-VBA solution to this.  If it's any consolation, you can store the VBA outside of the PowerPoint (in its own file) so that your PowerPoint does not become macro enabled.  Related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264820/powerpoint-vba-apply-shape-object-properties-to-selection/30267528

Comment: I change my mind and used the macro presented on that thread you gave me. That macro but configured my image "Height" and "Alignment" correctly but the Width didn't got the correct value. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Please [edit that into your original question](http://superuser.com/posts/922640/edit).  Code in the comments is nearly impossible to analyze.

Comment: Each shape has a .LockAspectRatio property. If this is set to true, then whenever you change the .Height, PowerPoint will also change the .Width to keep the shape's original proportions.  Likewise, if you change the .Width, it'll change the .Height.  If you don't mind having the shape distorted, you can change .LockAspectRatio to False before changing the .Height or .Width

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg , how can I put the " .LockAspectRatio=False " into the macro code in order to get exactly the height and width I want? I tried to put on the "OutputDetails" after the line "With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)" but it gave me an error...

Comment: That'd be the place to put it, and when I try it here, it works.  Follow Byron's suggestion, edit your original question to include the code in its current version and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the macro I used:

```
Dim w As Double
Dim h As Double
Dim l As Double
Dim t As Double

Sub StoreDetails()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        w = .Width
        h = .Height
        l = .Left
        t = .Top
    End With
End Sub

Sub OutputDetails()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        .Width = w
        .Height = h
        .Left = l
        .Top = t
    End With
End Sub
```

It configured my image "Height" and "Alignment" correctly but the Width didn't got the correct value. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Edit this into the question (and not as an answer).